# I forgot my AmazonAWS secret key, but I have a couple HMAC signed requests. How can I

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, hmac, hmacsha1

The signing function is as follows,

```
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', "{$method}\n{$server}\n{$uri}\n{$query_string}", MY_PRIVATE_KEY, true));
$signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($sig));
```

How can I deduce MY_PRIVATE_KEY, when I have all these parts
`{$method}\n{$server}\n{$uri}\n{$query_string}` and `$signature`, if possible at all?

Comment: you should create a new access key

Comment: Sure it's possible, with a botnet. Listen to what Dagon said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.*

`*` except with massive pools of servers to run a cracking operation. As [this quora answer states when talking about SHA256](http://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-brute-force-a-SHA-256-password-with-a-Mac-Pro-and-how-long-with-a-MacBook-Pro-theoretically), "If this is the case, your MacBook Pro will have dissipated into nothingness as part of the heat death of the universe before it finishes cracking that password".

Comment: That sounds awful. I don't think any MacBook like dissipation into nothingness.

Comment: I asked in case I missed anything.